# foreach PHP para Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Estou no meio de um projecto em que tenho fazer *clustering* num mapa. Encontrei este [algoritmo](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps) que se encontra em PHP. A minha duvida é neste `foreach`:

```
  foreach ($markers as $key => $target) {
        $pixels = pixelDistance($marker['lat'], $marker['lon'],
                                $target['lat'], $target['lon'],
                                $zoom);
        /* If two markers are closer than given distance remove */
        /* target marker from array and add it to cluster.      */
        if ($distance > $pixels) {
            printf("Distance between %s,%s and %s,%s is %d pixels.\n", 
                $marker['lat'], $marker['lon'],
                $target['lat'], $target['lon'],
                $pixels);
            unset($markers[$key]);
            $cluster[] = $target;
        }
    }
```

em que

```
$markers   = array();
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_1', 
               'lat' => 59.441193, 'lon' => 24.729494);
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_2', 
               'lat' => 59.432365, 'lon' => 24.742992);
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_3', 
               'lat' => 59.431602, 'lon' => 24.757563);
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_4', 
               'lat' => 59.437843, 'lon' => 24.765759);
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_5', 
               'lat' => 59.439644, 'lon' => 24.779041);
$markers[] = array('id' => 'marker_6', 
               'lat' => 59.434776, 'lon' => 24.756681);

$clustered = cluster($markers, 20, 11);
```

Como "traduzir" para Javascript?

Comment: Voce prefere Java, Javascript, ou tanto faz?

Comment: @bigown Pode ser javascript

Comment: Google Maps só suporta javascript. Favor alterar sua pergunta para especificar javascript e não confundir com Java

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz o meu objectivo não é aplicar o algoritmo num mapa de google maps mas sim adaptar para um outro tipo de mapa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor aqui é criar uma array de objectos.

Assim pode fazer:

```
var markers   = [];
markers.push = {id : 'marker_1', lat : 59.441193, lon : 24.729494);
// etc
```

E depois usar um for loop numérico. Exemplo:

```
var markers = [];
markers.push({
    id: 'marker_1',
    lat: 59.441193,
    lon: 24.729494
});
markers.push({
    id: 'marker_2',
    lat: 99.441193,
    lon: -24.729494
});
markers.push({
    id: 'marker_3',
    lat: -59.441193,
    lon: -24.729494
});
// etc

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var esteObjecto = markers[i];
    var id = esteObjecto.id;
    var lat = esteObjecto.lat;
    var lon = esteObjecto.lon;
    console.log(id, lat, lon);
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/BG8uZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript ainda não possui um equivalente ao `foreach` de linguagens como PHP, Perl, etc.

Uma possível solução é usar `for..in` com uma verificação extra:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        value = obj[key];
    }
}
```

Mas ao que parece, seu array possui índices numéricos, então a melhor forma é percorrê-lo com um loop `for` "comum":

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var value = myArray[i];

    var id = value['id'];
    var lat = value['lat'];
    // e assim por diante
}
```

Para remover um item de um array em Javascript, use o método `splice` do objeto Array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
array.splice(0) // remove o primeiro elemento do array
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de declarar o `i`.

Comment: Javascript não necessita de declaração de variáveis, porém é recomendavel utilizar `for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)` para que você tenha certeza que o `i` seja unico neste contexto e esteja `0`.

Comment: Muito bem observado, vou corrigir.